# Play Pause single button

Tags: java, android, button, media-player, playback

I am trying to implement play/pause in a single button however when i try to press it again it just stars the song again overlapping the sound playing. i have search ways and tried this method and it seems it is not working for me. thank you

```
private OnClickListener handler1 = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
    MediaPlayer mpE = MediaPlayer.create(GuitarTuner.this, R.raw.test2 );

        if (mpE.isPlaying()) {
            mpE.pause();
       } else {
           mpE.start();
       }

    }
};"
```

Comment: yes ? because you create, like, a new MediaPlayer each time you click the button ?

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the the media player every time. Instead try moving

`MediaPlayer mpE = MediaPlayer.create(GuitarTuner.this, R.raw.test2 );`

to outside of the handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
    MediaPlayer mpE = MediaPlayer.create(GuitarTuner.this, R.raw.test2 );

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mpE.isPlaying()) {
                    mpE.pause();
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                } else {

                    mpE.start();
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                }

            }
        });
```